# axios request to docker daemon

Tags: javascript, docker-compose, axios

Description:
In graphql gateway i would like to know the services available in docker so that i can stitch the schema from other graphql services. All the applications are running in a docker. docker compose file is used to start all the applications.
Docker engine does provide a REST api to list all the services.

Inside docker compose we should also mount volume

```
volume
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Problem:
I used npm library http and i was able to get the result

```
   const result = http.request(
      {
        socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock",
        path: "/containers/json",
      },
      (response) => {
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        res.on("data", (data) => console.log(data));
        res.on("error", (data) => console.error(data));
      }
    );
    result.end();
```

I am not able to get all the docker services using axios. I also find that even-though axios has socketPath attribute it do not have a path attribute along with it.

I used the following code will using axios:

```
const axiosResult = await axios({
  socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock",
  url: "/containers/json",
  method: "GET",
});
```

I tried most using a different url: **http://unix:/var/run/docker.sock/v1.30/containers/json**

Answer (score 1):

When using Axios the code has to modified as such to get the result

```
const { data } = await axios.get("http://unix:/containers/json", {
  socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock",
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Creating an instance with `baseURL: "http://unix:/", socketPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"` might be a handy way to handle all requests

Comment: Yes i agree... if we want to ask different information from Docker API :)